# Authorization gems for Sinatra

Tags: ruby, authorization, sinatra

I am working on a Sinatra project that needs some authorization. I am using OmniAuth for authentication, now I need something like CanCan for handling authorization. I'm new to Sinatra so I'm not sure if there is a common solution to this or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is [sinatra-can](https://github.com/shf/sinatra-can). According to the [README](https://github.com/shf/sinatra-can/blob/master/README.markdown) it "is a lightweight wrapper for the CanCan authorization library. It contains a partial implementation of CanCan's Rails helpers, but in Sinatra". So you can use the Ability file like you do with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) in Rails. It doesn't cover everythin CanCan does, but it aims to.